# Which kind of view is that? - IOS5

Tags: ios, ios5

Please, can you indicate me which kind of view is it?

Section 1.(red)
Section 2.(blue) it has scroll
section 3. (green)

[image]Many thanks

UPDATED

Comment: There's a bunch of views in that screenshot. Which one are you talking about??

Comment: Hi all,I have updated the screen shoot, I'm worried about blue 2 view,  and how to implement the scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. probably UIView with [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) added as subViews
2. probably [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). it could also be [UISCrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) populated programatically.
3. looks like [ADBannerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html), it could be custom banner based on UIImageView